# cordova 10 has CORS issue with allowList

Tags: cordova, cors, whitelist

I'm developing a cordova application for Android , and after switch to cordova 10 , there is an error related to CORS problem, I remove the cordova-plugin-whitelist because of Deprecation Notice :

> With the Allow List functionality now integrated into the core of Cordova Android (10.x and greater), this plugin is no longer required.

My config.xml file contains this line :

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Before switch to cordova 10 everything was fine, I'm googling these days but no result , tnx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

cordova-android 10.x moved to serving file via https:// protocol (WebAssetLoader) from the previous file:/// protocol. That means you need to change CORS settings on your server to allow the hostname under which your mobile app runs at. Default is https://localhost, but you could change the hostname using `<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />` setting (the protocol is not configurable.

If you don't change the hostname in Cordova, then you need to add https://localhost as allowed origin in your server configuration using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: tnx for your reply, "hostname" works great, but when I change value, I have to set "AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" setting to "true", otherwise at the start of the app I get this error "Application Error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ..." , Is there any security issues with setting the "AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" to "true" ?

Comment: AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled set to true puts you back to file:/// scheme, as it was before cordova-android 10. There are no security issues, the change was done because of the CORS problems with file:/// origin.

Comment: Is there any link you could share on the change to `https://` in cordova-android v10?

Comment: @trebor Cordova blog is a good source about what changed and why. WebAssetLoader is mentioned in the https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html blog entry, which also links to the PR https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1137 . In the end, the CORS issues come from the fact that Android Cordova apps are now running at `https://localhost` (unless changed), thus your backend servers need to allow `https://localhost` (or whatever you changed it into using the hostname preference).

Answer (score 13):

I just migrated my project from Cordova 9 to Cordova 10.1.1, now targeting Android 12 (API 31), along with Firebase for OAuth ([per the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova)).

The build went fine, but I started getting the `err_connection_refused` error trying to sign in via OAuth. The only thing required to resolve this was adding
the preference `name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true"`
to the `config.xml`.

Comment: This seems like a new question with a new answer, not an answer to the original question. Can you clarify why you think this is relevant to the original question? Also, can you provide more context for the configuration settings? (E.g., parent elements, so it's clear where this should be set.)

Comment: This is a valid answer, if lacking in explanation. Adding `<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />` to the `<platform name="android">` element reverts to the old behaviour of serving from the `file://` protocol, and thus resolves CORS errors.

Comment: I prefer this answer because I don't want to add localhost to my server

Comment: adding AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled will result in err_file_not_found file:///android_asset/www/index.html error