# Cordova iOS CORS configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cors, cordova-ios

I created a web based project and created an iOS app using Cordova. In my application, there is a php request in our app that is not connecting to the server from iOS and even on Android. I believe it is a CORS issue. How do I enable CORS in my application Xcode?

I added the following in my config.xml
`< access origin="*" /> < allow-navigation href="*" /> < allow-intent href="*" />`

Furthermore, I added the cordova-plugin-whitelist.
What am I missing so I can enable HTTPS requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cordova 10 has CORS issue with allowList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689633/cordova-10-has-cors-issue-with-allowlist)